# Cost of cleaning a rover up to COSPAR IVc standard

Tags: planetary-protection, mars-exploration-rover

To this date no rover or lander was able to access the so-called Mars Special Regions (like where seasonal flows occur) because of the required COSPAR IVc level (no more than 30 spores for the whole lander which is, if I got it right, the level achieved for the Viking landers).

I wonder whether there are any estimates of the costs for a modern generation rover (like Curiosity or Perseverance) sterilized up to this level.

Comment: I suspect the expensive part's having a working rover afterward. A good part of that seems likely to be design and manufacture of the rover and its instruments to survive the sterilization process.